# как распарсить POST HTTP запрос в CGI скрипте, используя только стандартную библиотеку в Питоне 2?

Tags: python, json, post

Подскажите как разобрать такой входящий POST запрос на стороне сервера используя python без фреймворков?
Интересует как достать значения `status, customer_name, customer_email, price`?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#--*--coding: utf-8--*--

import json
import requests

login = "test"
email = "j@ool.ru"
satoshi = 0.001

values = {
    "status": "confirmed",
    "payment_id": "WNk3l7uQGlnhAA3e",
    "settled_currency": "BTC",
    "server_time": 1408705349,
    "paid_amount": 0.12231,
    "reference": {
      "customer_name": login,
      "order_number": 123,
      "customer_email": email
    },
    "payment_url": "https://bitcoinpay.com/en/sci/invoice/btc/WNk3l7uQGlnhAA3e/",
    "price": "0.00100000",
    "settled_amount": "0.00099200"
  }
data = json.dumps(values)
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
request = requests.post('http://www.ьнышеу.ru/cgi-bin/btc/order-received.cgi', data=data, headers=headers)
```

Comment: 1- что вы считаете "фреймворком"? Является ли `http.server` фреймворком? Является ли `wsgiref`, `socket`?  2- Судя по урлу, вы хотите в итоге получить cgi скрипт. Так ли это? Какой сервер вы используете? Есть ли требование ограничиться только стандартной библиотекой? Какая версия Питона?

Comment: @jfs, Фреймворком считаю: bottle, flask, django... У меня просто не vds/vps, а обычный хостинг и там крайне не охотно ставят новые модули. А если они еще и не собраны под debian отдельно, то вообще не ставят (ставят только то, что можно поставить через `apt-get install` и то не охотно и приходится им долго объяснять, что оно мне необходимо. Всё верно, хочу cgi скрипт. Очень желательно ограничиться стандартной библиотекой, хотя из не стандартных имеется requests. Версия Python-2.7.9-1.

Comment: если вы можете загружать файлы на ваш хостинг такие как `order-received.cgi`, то ничего ставить не надо (`bottle`, `flask` написаны на чистом Питоне, [хоть в zip упакуйте и напрямую архив можно исполнять](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5355694/4279). Посмотрите как `requests` помещает в папку `requests/packages` другие пакеты (`chardet`, `urllib3`), не используя и не требуя их отдельной установки (из кода используются как: `from requests.packages import urllib3`) Другой пример: `pip` также тащит за собой копию `requests` в `pip/_vendor` папке, не требуя чтобы `requests` пакет был установлен.

Comment: @jfs, `bottle` вообще одним файликом сделан, но не заработал, выдав кучу ошибок (разбираться не стал, так как использовать его и не планировал, хотел просто протестить)

Comment: мы точно знаем, что bottle работает в общем случае. Поэтому упоминать неудачный запуск без желания разобраться -- бессмысленно (ни вам, ни будущим читателям это не поможет).

Answer (score 2):

Переданные данные (тело POST запроса) доступны на стандартном вводе (`sys.stdin`). Чтобы их прочитать можно использовать обычные методы: `.read()`, `for line in sys.stdin` итд.

Переданные HTTP заголовки устанавливаются http-сервером, который запускает cgi-скрипт, как переменные окружения, например `Content-Length` заголовок доступен как `os.environ['CONTENT_LENGTH']`.

Чтобы распознать запрос, сгенерированный кодом в вопросе:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import json
import os
import sys

print "Content-Type: text/plain\n" # send http response headers

data = json.loads(sys.stdin.read(int(os.environ['CONTENT_LENGTH'])))
print data['reference']['customer_name'] # send http response body
```

Этот cgi-скрипт печатает `test` (`customer_name`) на отдельной строчке.

Для отладки полезно добавить сверху:

```
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()  # XXX for debugging
```

Можно использовать `os.environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'`, чтобы различить GET/POST http-запросы.

See also, [How to run CGI “hello world” with python http.server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30516414/4279).

Comment: спасибо, работает! только я не совсем понял это место `int(os.environ['CONTENT_LENGTH'])))` Для чего этот заголовок туда помещается. типа читать данные с этого заголовка? у меня работает и в таком виде: 
`data = json.loads(sys.stdin.read())`
также не пойму насчёт заголовка. я отсылаю себе заголовок bpsignature, но когда пытаюсь его прочитать `header = os.environ['BPsignature']` получаю ошибку `KeyError: 'BPsignature'`

Comment: а всё. разобрался с заголовком. он стал называться HTTP_BPSIGNATURE

Comment: `sys.stdin.read()` читает до конца соединения (до EOF). Это зависает на моей машине (чтобы это работало  -- клиент должен отдельно закрывать концы на отсылку (`sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)`) и приём или вообще не читать ответа). `Content-Length` HTTP заголовок говорит сколько байт надо читать, не ожидая пока соответствующая половинка соединения будет закрыта.

Comment: понял. спасибо. теперь осталось разобраться почему, когда после `json.loads` пытаюсь получить значение переменной на сервере возникает ошибка `TypeError: string indices must be integers`. Хотя беру тот же ответ(записываю в файл) и у себя локально пробую.. всё работает, отсылаю свой post с подобными данными, тоже всё работает.. в смысле могу получить значение имени, статуса и т.д., а на сервере ошибка.

Comment: @SergeyWhite: `print repr(data)` может объяснить почему. Не пытайтесь выполнить `"abc"["s"]`. Но это уже похоже на отдельный (простой) вопрос.

Comment: ну да с этим уже разберусь самостоятельно. `print `использовать не могу, поэтому пишу в файл. в файл естественно ответ не запишешь, поэтому приходится преобразовывать в `str`, но что `str,` что `repr` дают такой результат `{u'status' ....}` поидее `u'` не должна влиять на эту ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Если предположить что всё бежит за каким-то cgi, то вам необходимо приблизительно следующее:

```
import cgi, cgitb 

form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
status = form.getvalue('status')
...
```

Для разбора такого тела запроса как в вопросе может подойти `json.load`:

```
import sys, json

request = json.load(sys.stdin)
status = request.get('status')
customer_email = request.get('reference').get('customer_email')
```

Comment: да. я так тоже думал. но вот что из этого вышло:
`import cgi
resp = cgi.FieldStorage()
status = resp.getfirst("status", "")`
ошибка: TypeError: not indexable

если попытаться: `json.loads(resp)` - Ошибка: TypeError: expected string or buffer
если: `json.loads(str(resp))` Ошибка: ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
если записать в файл результат запроса `f.write( str(resp))`, то увидим:
`FieldStorage(None, None, '{"status": "timeout", "payment_id":.`
почему выводится `FieldStorage(None, None `?
а не сразу `{"status":.`. и т.д.

Comment: в ответе пользователя @jfs вы можете увидеть как сервер сообщает размер сообщения и каким образом серверу приложений сообщить о типе читаемого сообщения прямо из вашего скрипта.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'`