# Управление JSON-запросами на стороне сервера (Python)

Tags: python, json, cgi

Имеется очень простой CGI сервер на Питоне. Ему со стороны клиента (JS) отправляется запрос:

```
var json = JSON.stringigy({foo: "bar", baz: [0, 1, 2]});
var xhr = new XmlHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/cgi-bin/script.py", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
xhr.send(json);
```

script.py должен получить этот JSON, распарсить и, желательно отослать клиенту (изменив, естественно).
Заранее извиняюсь за нубскй вопрос, весь день раскал по Гуглу, ничего не нашел.

Comment: А вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: что пробовали сделать, что не получилось? сервер слушает, принимает, обрабатывает, отправляет обратно, в чем проблема?

Comment: Я не знаю как реализовать сервер.

Comment: Не нашел информации о том, как на Питоне обрабатывать "application/json".

Comment: @EvaBob ищите лучше. [Вот](https://mafayyaz.wordpress.com/2013/02/08/writing-simple-http-server-in-python-with-rest-and-json/) пример простого http-сервера из первой поисковой выдачи. Кстати, вы написали сначала, что "*...Имеется очень простой CGI сервер...*". А говорите, не имеется.

Comment: @approximatenumber Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ТС говорит о том, что не знает, как реализовать сервер и не нашел информации по этому вопросу. КАКИМ минимальным ответом (скорей, в моем случае, комментарием) на такой общий вопрос и такую абстрактную проблему ТС может быть, кроме ссылок и прочего? Я задаю скорей риторический вопрос.

Comment: В этому случае, предположу, что стоит закрыть вопрос. Но что–то подсказывает, что минимальный пример все–таки возможен.

Answer (score 1):

Вот работающий пример:

script.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import json
myjson = json.loads(sys.stdin.read(int(os.environ['CONTENT_LENGTH'])))

# здесь мы что-то меняем в данных
myjson['baz'] = range(100)

# возвращаем данные 
print 'Content-Type: application/json'
print 'Content-Length: ', len(json.dumps(myjson))
print 'Connection: keep-alive'
print 'Content-Language: ru'
print
print json.dumps(myjson)    # or "json.dump(result, sys.stdout)"
```

и у вас пара ошибок в коде JS, вот мой пример:

```
var json = JSON.stringify({foo: "bar", baz: [0, 1, 2]});
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/cgi-bin/script.py", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
xhr.send(json);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    var json = xhr.response;
    console.log(json);
}
```

взято [отсюда](https://gist.github.com/simbha/6918085)

Comment: Следует `Content-Length` http-заголовок использовать при чтении, иначе сервер может зависнуть, ожидая конца соединения, которое может не наступить никогда. См.  [как распарсить POST HTTP запрос в CGI скрипте, используя только стандартную библиотеку в Питоне 2?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/497284/23044)